# In midnight commander, how to select a large continuous range of files

Tags: mc

Is there some thing similar to the shift mouse left click in GUI file explorers? Basically something to mark the start and end of the selection, and selects anything in between?

My scenario is, I sometimes need to sort the imported photos by modify time, then selects one day of them.

I'm aware of ctrl-T, and shift-+. However, ctrl-t requires to go over every file in the selection, so it's slow. Shift-+ won't work, because it's based on pattern matching on file name, not on modify time.

I am also aware of shift up/down arrow in mc. It would be good if shift page-up/page-down can select a page-ful of files, but it doesn't.

Comment: Switch to FAR manager. It can do Shift+PgUp and Shift+PgDn. And many more.

Comment: @WhiteOwl are you referring to [far2l](https://github.com/elfmz/far2l)?   please include a link when you refer to "non-standard" tools. A name alone often isn't enough to find software (although in this case, i found far2l easily enough with `apt cache search -n ^far`).  That said, it's nice to hear about an alternative to [mc](https://www.midnight-commander.org/), especially if it's better in significant ways.

Comment: Check this later: https://midnight-commander.org/ticket/4448